# Where can I find a simple spreadsheet or grid control for VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

Can someone recommend a spreadsheet control other than the OWC webcomponents with very simple functionality? I just need a 2x100 matrix and the ability for user input. I need this for VB.NET and I need it to be compatible with both 32bit and 64bit systems. I don't know anything about the grid control.

What is the best way to get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used [this](http://www.farpointspread.com/spread/?gclid=CN30z_Dl85oCFQVfFQodVyxZdw) - but looks good.

Comment: looking for something thats free :)

Comment: @alex - ok - you didn't mention free in your original post - sory.